# Displaying $2 \cdot 10^5$ as $200000$

Tags: maple, floating-point

How can I in Maple write out the number $2 \cdot 10^5$, so it displays the full number with all digits: $200000$?

By typing increasing zeros I can test Maples treshold, and I get:

$$20\\200\\2000\\20000\\2 \cdot 10^5\\2 \cdot 10^6\\\ \vdots$$ How can I change this setting in Maple to show me more digits before using $2 \cdot 10^n$?

Comment: Right click on the result, Numeric formatting.

Comment: So simple. Thanks.